# ReverseGeocodeCurrentLocation Error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I`m working at auto-location current position. I've got this exception trying to compile directly on the telephone. But when I compile on the emulator, it works perfect.[image]

The problem appears in this line:

```
IList<Address> addressList =
            await geocoder.GetFromLocationAsync(_currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude, 10);
```

The full method is:

```
async Task<Address> ReverseGeocodeCurrentLocation()
    {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

        IList<Address> addressList =
            await geocoder.GetFromLocationAsync(_currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude, 10);

        Address address = addressList.FirstOrDefault();
        return address;
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: click "Break".  Look at the stack trace and determine **exactly** which line is causing the exception.  Use the debugger to figure out which value is null, then figure out why.

Comment: @Jason, this line cause the exception: `IList<Address> addressList =
            await geocoder.GetFromLocationAsync(_currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude, 10);`

Comment: are you sure _currentLocation has a value?

Comment: @Jason, it is null when I compile on mobile. But when I compile on the emulator, there are values and it works

Comment: How are you getting _currentLocation?  Are you sure you are requesting the right permissions in the manifest?

Comment: @Jason, I have this permissions in manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />` Now I am looking how I get _currentLocation.

Comment: I change _currentLocation here: `public async void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            _currentLocation = location;
            if (_currentLocation == null)
            {
                _locationTextGlobalVariable = "Unable to determine your location. Try again in a short while.";
            }
            else
            {
                _locationTextGlobalVariable = string.Format("{0:f6},{1:f6}", _currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude);
            `

Comment: please edit your question to include additional code, don't just paste it as a comment.  And it sounds as if you're attempting to reverse geocode your location BEFORE you've successfully determined the location.  Logically you should wait for the first operation to succeed before you attempt the second.